# Call method within controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How does one call a function from within the same controller? I'm trying to just use an index() function in my controller to route to other function. This seems very basic, but I can't find an answer to it anywhere. I'm using Laravel 4

```
public function index(){
    $this->testView();
}

public function testView(){
    return View::make('test');
}
```

Comment: Is there any error messages?

Comment: nope, it just doesn't load the view so I'm left with a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a value.

```
return $this->testView();
```

Comment: great, I knew it was something simple. I'll mark you as correct when it allows me